# How difficult to creat a simple eraser effect on core animation or core graphic?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-animation, core-graphics

Hi i will like to create an eraser animation or core graphic that looks like rubbing away the current content and add in a new content on a uibutton when i tapped on the view or button.

is it tough to do it ?, any tutorial or web link to show how to do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi, we can use this eraser functionality with core animation in our app like below:

```
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:imgBlankView];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [imgBlankView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, imgBlankView.frame.size.height)];

        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),lineWidth);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);

        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());  
        CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint1.x, lastPoint1.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        imgBlankView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        lastPoint1 = currentPoint;
```

Use this code for erase the drowning which you draw with the core animation like circle ,rectangle or any CALayer like drowning with this code.

Put this code in your touch move method and as per user touches on the view it erase that on with this code  enjoy erasing functionality with this code.

Comment: thanks Dhanesh, for the quick reply... will it work for button?... i will tap on the button, and the animation will erase an image or view and replaced with another image.

Comment: can u please describe in detail that what r u drawing on the view or on the image?

Comment: thanks for the reply, Dhanesh.
i not very good in explaining, i have attached a picture to explain..
i wanna have a an eraser effect whenever the user tapped on the button or image it will erase the current image and replace another image..

Comment: k so u have both image 6 & 2 or u can replace 6 with 2 as looking like it erasing the old image and draw new image for that use fade in fade out animation on the imageview it simply available on the google or otherwise check this link http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/03/10/Animate-fade-inout.aspx

Comment: is an array of pictures, that will erase and change to another. is link to structure of a body to mix and match design...