# Memory leak crashing my GPUImage camera app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image-processing, gpuimage

I'm having some issues when trying to capture more than 1 photo. The app becomes slow and then it crashes because of several memory warning. I am using Brad's **GPUImage** library. Here are some methods in which I use it:

//the creation of the camera view

```
- (IBAction)photoFromCamera
{
    imageView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] init];

    stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    //stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

    filter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
    [filter prepareForImageCapture];
    [stillCamera addTarget:filter];

    [stillCamera addTarget:imageView];

    [filter addTarget:imageView];
    [stillCamera startCameraCapture];

    UIButton * shotButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    shotButton.frame = CGRectMake(137, 361, 46, 30);
    [shotButton setTitle:@"Take!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [shotButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shotAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [imageView addSubview:shotButton];

    UIButton * cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 55, 40);
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [imageView addSubview:cancelButton];
}
```

//The take photo action

```
-(void)shotAction:(UIImagePickerController *)photoPicker{
    [stillCamera capturePhotoAsPNGProcessedUpToFilter:filter withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *processedPNG, NSError *error) {
        self.saveButton.enabled = YES;
        self.filterButton.enabled = YES;
        self.cropButton.enabled = YES;

        originalFirstImage = [UIImage imageWithData:processedPNG];

        [self.selectedImageView setImage:originalFirstImage];
    }];

    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

is there something wrong? I'm using ARC, is there something that is not releasing?
Thanks for your comments.

EDIT: the error is: **Terminated due to Memory Pressure**

Comment: One thing I can see you are capturing self in block. And block will capture it as strong reference, will be creating retain cycle. It should be weak pointer to self.

Comment: @C_X in my header I have them like:

`property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *filterButton;
property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *cropButton; `
should I change them to class variables?

Comment: if you are accessing self, it will retain self, and self will retain block, I think its retain cycle... access self as weak pointer

Answer (score 3):

Shot action method have block, and block using self. Block always capture its environment, means it will reference every thing strongly. So it will cause a retain cycle, which will not allow to free memory. You should access self with weak pointer. I will suggest you that

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

and use this weakSelf in block.

**EDIT**

GPUImage library also have some memory leak issues reported, read this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rubymotion/3zqh1cev03Y/_BEMOVxo3DsJ)

Comment: The error keeps happening, I forgot to tell you that Im using PECrop for cropping my images, but I think it will not take a part on this problem...

Comment: it will be better if you show some stack trace... And also app with leak and allocation instrument, it will help you narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Run allocation instrument and run app, you will find the place where memory not geting de allocated and app crashes...

Comment: I will do it right now and will let you know the results. Great suggestion.

Comment: All Heap Allocations are really consuming when taking the photo only. Its incredible. I will make the leak instrument now.

Comment: are these allocations  in GPUIimage library?

Comment: Inside the "All Heap Allocations" most of them are from Foundation, Core Graphics and Core Media.

Comment: :) Then it is possible CPUImage library doing some drawing using CGContext , and not freeing up the memory effectively...

Comment: Its not true memory leak, but it is the case of unbounded memory growth, where objects don't get time to deallocat and app will dead due to memory issue, If CGContext is doing some drawing in it, then bit map memory should be release right after drwaing is done...

Comment: But I'm not using `CGContext` nowhere! this is getting hard to find :(

Comment: May be  GPUImage library is using that... not sure, but there are many threads on internet about  GPUImage leak issues.

Comment: Yes they are... well, thanks for the help anyway. Really a pleasure, glad to have people on Stack like you man!

Comment: @C_X What would be "unbounded memory growth"? Is there a way we could avoid that in our code in a general sense? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unbounded memory growth happens where memory continues to be allocated and is never given a chance to be deallocated...! Some time we cache some objects we put them in some dictionary but we never remove them, that can cause unbounded memory growth. We don't call them real memory leaks because when those collection or block will finish and there will be no reference they will dealloct. But if they are more and we will never get a chance to de-allocate and iOS watch dog will kill our app.

Comment: You can track them by allocation instrument. If allocated memory is get up and up you... just check system trace the elements is black belongs to your code, and in grey are basically system libraries.. UIKIT and CoreGraphics do allocate a lot of memory if not use very well

Comment: @C_X Thanks for response. I am still trying to get my head around the part "cache some objects we put them in some dictionary but we never remove them..", because once we `dealloc` the `NSDictionary` all the references it retains will be dealloc'ed automatically. (would be nice if you could cite an example, but I am afraid I might be asking too much here), but +1.

Comment: yes you are right. I am saying some thing else, e.g if we downloading some images and we putting them in some collection might be dictionary or array what ever. and we not using them all but using some of them, now they will be consuming memory, so my point was we should remove things which will be no more in our use continuously. This might be not in your case but this is one example how unbounded memory growth happens. Or some time we are allocating temporary objects in loop and we are not releasing them, these object will dealloct when autorelease pool will drain, but may be if  too much,

Comment: if too much temporary objects we don't get chance to take advantage from pool drain, we will be killed by iOS.

Comment: If I find the answer, I will tell you guys. Hope to find it, I don't want to use another framework for taking photos.

Comment: @C_X - In regards to that Google Groups thread, note that this is among people trying to use this with RubyMotion. RubyMotion has had problems with memory leaks inside itself: http://joshsymonds.com/blog/2013/06/26/why-im-not-using-rubymotion-in-production/ and note that the solution proposed there (adding `[super dealloc]`) seems to imply that they have ARC turned off for this project, when GPUImage requires ARC to run properly. I'm not saying GPUImage lacks memory buildup somewhere, but that Google Groups thread is probably not a good resource.

Comment: Also, this isn't due to a retain cycle from that block. The block is executed inline with the code above, and is not retained past that point. The block and everything it references (including self) is properly deallocated after that point. Using a weak reference doesn't help you at all here.

Comment: Yes that what we figure out that this is not due to this, And I suggest using __weak because its best practice when you are dealing with blocks. You may suggest some thing better here..! I was thinking this might be due to CoreGraphics objects not get time to release, like if doing drawing with CGContext, and could not free memory due to which app start crash. One thing I understand by all this discussion is that, its not retain or true memory leak, it is unbounded memory growth and it is also possible it is happening due to GPUImage, Because seeing this code I can say issue is not here.

Comment: @BradLarson I think you are the author of this library, You can give some expert opinion. It will be very helpful if you point out in some direction.

Comment: @BradLarson Hi Brad, its a pleasure. Can you give me some tips on what is going on?

Comment: @C_X Hey man, how are you? got a question for you. Is there a way to erase a UIImageView photo with the finger on iOS? Is it there any library to do this?

Comment: There is nothing which iOS provide you.. but you can do this by creating eraser effect using by blending things and use some graphics  work.

Comment: Here are some links which may help you, quite cool and easy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502320/eraser-not-working-in-ios-drawing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441916/how-difficult-to-creat-a-simple-eraser-effect-on-core-animation-or-core-graphic