# Implementing an eraser function in Quartz (draw transparent)

Tags: quartz-2d

I can't figure out how to draw a Quartz path that "draws" transparent over the image. I've tried `[NSColor clearColor]CGColor]`, `kCGBlendModeClear`, and `CGContextClearRect`, but I can't figure out how to erase (set to transparent) pixels in a CGContext. [Note: the  platform in question is Macintosh]

Comment: possibly duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441916/how-difficult-to-creat-a-simple-eraser-effect-on-core-animation-or-core-graphic

Comment: The example you cited is for iOS. I'm having trouble getting this working on OS X.

Comment: Ah I see. I have no experience there, I suggest you edit your question to clarify. Good luck!